# Reactjs bookmark url with parameters

Tags: reactjs, http, react-router

I have a search component where the user type the name and location of a business, which will be sent to the server to retreive the data that match name and location values.
once I receive a response from the server I use `React Router` to redirect to `Search Page` component with parameters , also the router allow me to pass the data in `props.location.state` so I was able to use the data in the `Search Page` component  below is the code

```
 handleSearchSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        Axios.post('http://localhost:9000/api/search', {
           name : this.state.name,
           location: this.state.location 
        })
        .then(res => {
            const {history} = this.props
            history.push({
                pathname: '/search',
                search: `?name=${this.state.name}&location=${this.state.location}`,
                state: { data: res.data, name: this.state.name, location: this.state.location  }
            })
        })
    }
```

my question is :

if I user would like to Bookmark the url, what is the best way to retrieve the data from the server on a URL GET request>

I was thinking to parse the search parameters that the react router send as props (bellow) and resend another http , but I am not sur how and also if this is the best approach

```
location:
hash: ""
key: "qxte3t"
pathname: "/search"
search: "?name=Restaurantf&location=Paris"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is correct. When your component is mounted after a user clicks on the bookmarked link, you should check for existing state (e.g. existing lists of results in case you got there from somewhere else within the app).
If the state is empty, you could use something like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to parse the URL parameters and make a http call to your backend and present your results.